# How to pass a buffer of binary data from C to C# with pinvoke

Tags: c#, arrays, interop, pinvoke

I have a DLL coded in C that has functions that output image data as unsigned char *, convert between different image formats and so on. I have a client who wants to make use of this from C#. I guess that the apppropriate data type on the C# side would be byte [].

I thought that PInvoke would help, but I cant find the appropriate technique to marshall this "binary data" to C# (whose variable length is stored in a separate variable). All the marshalling examples I have seen concern null terminated strings and an image array does not stop at an ascii null.

I have seen that I might alternatively consider passing the pointer to the data via an IntPtr but it
looks like this would involve unsafe code on the C# side.

Comment: You can use IntPtr without unsafe. Use methods of Marshal class. You might marshal with byte[] also. So ideas as to what your functions look like would help.

Comment: What we really need to know is who invokes the interop (managed side or unmanaged side), and what the data is and which way it flows.

Answer (score 1):

You want to allocate global memory,  [GlobalAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366574(v=vs.85).aspx)

Then in C#, you need to marshall the pointer to a managed type.

For a string I am using the following code, (you can adapt it to your needs):

```
 public static string GetString() {
        IntPtr str = mylib.getstring(); //get native pointer
        if (str == IntPtr.Zero)
            return null;

        string newStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(str); //marshall to managed string
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(str); //free memory

        return newStr;
    }
```

Edit: Forgot to mention how to PInvoke your library:

```
class mylib {
   [DllImport("mylib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public extern static IntPtr getstring();
}
```

Also don't forget to import System.Runtime.InteropServices

Comment: Thankyou, actually my C functions generally write into a preallocated char *buffer.

Comment: Actually FreeHGlobal matches LocalAlloc.

Comment: I suppose that pathStr is a typo in your answer (it's not declared). I dont see where the length of the string is set. I tried adapting your code and got a string of length zero.

Comment: The Microsft doc says Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi copies all characters up to the first null character. So this function is not appropriate to the problem as I had stated it.

Comment: The two-argument version ov PtrToString is closer to what I need: the first argument is as before (str) and the second argument is the number of characters to copy.

Comment: Check this, you have to pass the size too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Why aren't you fixing the error that I pointed out. Instead of GlobalAlloc you mean to write LocalAlloc.

Comment: Well I can't understand why it is wrong. Can you explain please?

Answer (score 0):

OK, George TG's answer set me on the right path, (thankyou!) but suppose that we have a function with signature 
void fillBytes(unsigned char *outBytes, int nbBytes); 
on the C side that writes nbBytes into the array at outBytes then the C#side could be written as this:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("FixedSizeString", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void fillBytes(IntPtr buffer, int nbBytes);
    void main(string[] args)
    {
        int BUFFSIZ = 256;// corresponds to the number of bytes in the buffer
        IntPtr iptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(BUFFSIZ);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFSIZ];
        if (iptr == IntPtr.Zero)
            Console.WriteLine("Allocation failed");
        else
        {
            fillBytes(iptr, BUFFSIZ);
            for (int i = 0; i < BUFFSIZ; ++i)
            {
                buffer[i] = Marshal.ReadByte(buffer, i);
            }
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(iptr);
            // now deal with buffer here ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use [Marshal.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx) instead of the loop to copy the data back from the unmanaged buffer.  The loop will be very expensive.